# Convert all geo TIFF in a directory in ASCII

Tags: qgis, gdal, geotiff-tiff, esri-ascii-raster

I would like to convert all geoTIFF in a directory in ASCII with the use of a command like `gdal_translate -of GTiff`... in OSGeo4W Shell.

Is this possible?

Comment: Almost everything is possible. You should give some more detail, so users can understand your problem.

Comment: other than the actual gdal_translate command parameters (which you seem to know) this is a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged the question with QGIS: gdal_translate is also used in QGIS menu Raster > Conversion > Translate. In here you can select batch mode for for processing a whole directory.

As for a commandline solution check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691943/how-to-loop-through-several-files-using-gdal-and-cmd